# Segment Anything Model on ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, image-segmentation

I downloaded Meta's [Segment Anything Model](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b67b441f29f4ce6810979f5f0667ebe) (SAM) and the needed deep learning libraries for ArcGIS Pro 3.1. I then added the Sentinel-2 image with 10 meters resolution, with 3 bands (B3, B4 and B8), 8-bit unsigned.

I open the Detect Objects Using Deep Learning tool to generate the image segmentation, add the image and the downloaded SAM as stated in [this guide](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/pretrained-models/latest/imagery/using-segment-anything-model-sam-.htm), but when I try to run it, this warning message appears:

"Warning 003387 Input raster cell size 0.000090 is not within the cell size range [0.000002, 0.000002] the Deep Learning model has been trained for. Results may not be optimal. Consider setting another cell size in the environment, or using a different raster input, or using another Deep Learning model."

I tried to resample the image, leaving it with the resolution that the warning suggests (0.000002, 0.000002), but the warning persists and an empty result is outputted.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a warning, you can try running the algorithm on your image and see the output.

Comment: @Padmanabha although its just a warning the result is empty (no polygons) so that it seems something related to this warning is affecting the output. Any ideas? (PS.: the contributor is a colleague of mine)

Comment: I used the algorithm in a drone image and it worked despite the warning. Here you are using Sentinel-2 with non RGB Bands while as far as I know, SAM is used in RGB bands (the drone image had the same). You can try with RGB combination.